# Displaying IP On LCD Display

Tags: python, lcd

I am trying to get my raspberry Pi to display it's IP to my LCD display. I need to execute this command 'hostname -I' using python in a python script I have almost successfully made , grab the result text( which will be the IP) string, and pass it to my 20x4 LCD display. This is my attempt:

```
  j=os.popen("hostname -I")
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string(str(j),1)
```

I am getting no errors however my LCD display is saying: `<open file 'hostname'` and then it cuts off.

Comment: My LCD is saying: "<open file 'hostname" and then it cuts off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding [Dr.Rabbit's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73773/29510) a little, what you want to do is actually run a shell command (`hostname -I`), which returns the IP address of the machine running that command. As the Python script you're running is one process and the shell command is also another process, what you need to do from your Python script is

- run the shell command
- wait till it has run
- retrieve in a variable the text (the IP address) it has written to the subprocess' standard output, which you send to the display

and [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) does exactly that. What [popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) does is only prepare a sub-process, which the calling script still needs to interact with hence the *bizarre* garbage text you noticed.

However note that `shell = True` poses a security risk:

> ### [17.1.1. Using the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)
>
> **Warning** : Using `shell=True` can be a security hazard. See the warning under [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details.

A safer approach would be to run command `hostname -I` and clean up the returned text from within Python:

```
import subprocess

IP = subprocess.check_output(["hostname", "-I"]).split()[0]
print str(IP)

#send it to the LCD
lcd_string(str(IP),1)
```

Comment: I agree this is the better approach, unless your in a closed network.

Answer (score 1):

Run it using subprocess

```
import subprocess

cmd = "hostname -I | cut -d\' \' -f1"
IP = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
print str(IP)

#send it to the LCD
lcd_string(str(IP),1)
```